# Saving a cleaned dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

i'm working on cleaning a huge dataset, i've finished to clean it and want to save it in a new CSV
So i can start a new notebook from the cleaned.CSV
The problem is when i save it into a new CSV i lost a lot of data.
See below my first df.info with 307381 non-null everywhere and Index: 307381 entries, 6 to 999755.

[image]

So i use the folowing code to save it:

`df.to_csv('cleaned.csv',";")`

then i open this new dataset (suppose to be cleaned) in df1

and i have a completely uncleaned dataset see second picture
RangeIndex: 313300 entries, 0 to 313299
and differents value in "non-null"

If you have a solution, i would be happy to hear about it.

[image]

Comment: you are saving df not df2. maybe that's why. make a new dataframe and save it

Comment: when i do df.info(), just before saving, that's mean that df is the last version of my dataframe no? so shouldn't change anything to rename it on df2?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i finaly found my answer, as i couldn't found on stackoverflow, i will post  it here.

to keep all cleaned (datetime, object .....) we need to use

```
df.to_pickle("cleaned.csv")
```

And to open it later use this:

```
df_cleaned = pd.read_pickle("cleaned.csv")
```